# Pidfile not found when try to start the Contextbroker as system service

Tags: fiware-orion

I got this problem frequently when I try to upgrade my standalone instance to a new version, Its easy solved creating a pid file manually.
But at this time installing the new version 0.14.0, I've made everything that I know, even a clean install and this "step" not worked. Maybe the new updates should be available by yum update command.

```
[root@~]# /etc/init.d/contextBroker start
Starting...
contextBroker is stopped
Starting contextBroker...                         cat: /var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid: No such file or directory
pidfile not found                                          [FAILED]
```

When I run it in FG(contextBroker -fg) its works fine, thats way 'm using to do it.

**That's my `curl localhost:1026/version` output:**

```
<orion>
  <version>0.14.0</version>
  <uptime>0 d, 0 h, 1 m, 59 s</uptime>
  <git_hash>5e3d210e4b15fa9ebbfa07c93dd41f8b41697d0e</git_hash>
  <compile_time>nodate</compile_time>
  <compiled_by>fermin</compiled_by>
  <compiled_in>centollo</compiled_in>
</orion>
```

Addictionaly this is my MD5 checksum output:

```
[root@~]# md5sum /usr/bin/contextBroker
d3f24c4670a9d25a22c8877c3cdcc2b4  /usr/bin/contextBroker
```

---

How can I solve that?

Comment: Just to discard wether the problem is in the /etc/init.d/contextBroker script or in CB itself, could you edit your question to tell if running the CB in foreground works, please? i.e. run `contextBroker -fg` in a shell terminal, then do a `curl localhost:1026/version` in another shell.

Comment: Edited!
So its working as foregound.

Comment: After a reboot, thats back to work. I can't recreate this scenario and debug what reason the pid file is missing at 1st start of contextBroker as Service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that if for any reason (e.g. in some updates) the PID file doesn't exist or its content is not aligned with the actual PID of the process running in memory, the `/etc/init.d/contextBroker` service script may fail to stop the broker.

Thus, you can apply the following procedure:

1. Check there is an existing contextBroker process already running.
2. That process doesn't stop after `/etc/init.d/contextBroker stop` or `/etc/init.d/contextBroker restart`
3. Get the PID of the process (hint: use `ps ax | grep contextBroker`), then `kill`on that PID

After killing that process, `/etc/init.d/contextBroker start` should work again.

Thanks to Massimiliano Nigrelli at his team to help debuging this issue.

Comment: This problem still exists  `contextBroker[3674]: Starting contextBroker...                         cat: /var/run/contextBroker/contextBroker.pid: No such file or directory`
Maybe the contextBroker should be updated to the new systemd services instead using the legacy `rc.d/init.d` the systemd directive has more complex and realibe ways to control daemons.

Comment: Alternatively is possible to use the contextBroker as a systemd service https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3474

Answer (score -2):

Uninstall and re-install ContextBroker works like a charm!

Comment: Hi @TelsaM, welcome to SO! Please provide more detail to your answer, as it looks a bit lacking. Also take a look at [how to provide a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the help center.